# Using getopts to grep a file and export it to a file: why is another parameter mentioned?

Tags: bash, unix, getopts

I use getopts to obtain a MAC address and grep that MAC address through log files. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":m:hx:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    m)
        cat /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log | grep $OPTARG | grep VCAS080455
        cat /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log | grep $OPTARG | grep VCAS080285
        cat /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log | grep $OPTARG | grep VCAS080290
      ;;
    h)
        echo "./search_mac.sh -m <mac address> will filter the logs by mac address"
        echo "./search_mac.sh -h will print this message"
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

I want to export the result to a file when the `-x` option is used:

```
./search_mac.sh -m 00067B6D87F0 -x /home/nico/extract.txt
```

I don't understand at this point how to obtain the argument from -x to be into my m) part of my case.

A little help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You win a UUOC (Useless Use of Cat) Award.  Three times!  Why not: `grep "$OPTARG" /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log | grep -E 'VCAS080455|VCAS080285|VCAS080290'` so you only scan the log file once.  You could reduce the second grep to `grep -E 'VCAS080(455|285|290)'` without straining the brain cells too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is to save the values of the option-arguments in shell variables, and then run your commands at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

m_arg=
x_arg=

while getopts ":m:hx:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    m) m_arg="$OPTARG" ;;
    x) x_arg="$OPTARG" ;;
    h)
        echo "./search_mac.sh -m <mac address> will filter the logs by mac address"
        echo "./search_mac.sh -h will print this message"
        exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

if [[ "$x_arg" ]] ; then
    exec > "$x_arg"          # redirect STDOUT to argument of -x
fi

< /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log grep -- "$m_arg" | grep VCAS080455
< /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log grep -- "$m_arg" | grep VCAS080285
< /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log grep -- "$m_arg" | grep VCAS080290
```

That said . . . this option doesn't seem all that useful to me, since `-x /home/nico/extract.txt` would just mean the same thing as `> /home/nico/extract.txt`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer. I'm still a noob at bash. I'm not quite sure how the redirect works in your example. Is it a typo or should there be $x_arg in front of your redirect such as it would be : $x_arg < /var/log/vmlog/Verimatrix.log grep -- "$m_arg" | grep VCAS080455 ?

Comment: The `exec` notation with no command and only I/O redirection means that from that point in the script onwards, the I/O redirection is changed.  In this case, anything that writes to standard output will now have its output go to whatever is in `$x_arg` (`/home/nico/extract.txt`).

Comment: Thanks again :)
You are correct ultimately what I want is just > <some path to a file>

But that file would be variable and that's why it's a parameter. I just don't know any better way... Yet.

Comment: Note that you can do: `file=/home/nico/extract.txt; ./search_mac.sh -m 00067B6D87F0 > $file`.  That is, the file name in a redirection can be specified by a variable.